# Z-Index of DrawingVisual on VisualHost

Tags: wpf

**UPD:** Solved. Look my comment

I have a VisualHost control with overriden

`VisualChildrenCount` and `GetVisualChild(int index)`.

Also it has a collection of Visuals

`public List<Visual> Children { get; set; }`

When i reorder items in the collection, their z-index for HitTest changes, but it displays still in wrong order.

**Question:** Should display order change or not ? If not then how can i change the display order of elements ?

On the image you can see that Rectangle is drawn nearly first, but oval and arc appear behind it. 
[image]
Thanks.

P.S. Of Course, after reordering i call InvalidateVisual()

Comment: Looks like the problem was in `List<Visual>`. After converting to `VisualCollection` problem was solved.

Comment: you should make this comment an answer and 'accept' it... or delete the question

Comment: Don't you know about the restriction for ones who have < 100 rep ? It is impossible to answer the question first 8 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in `List<Visual>`. After converting to `VisualCollection` and removing `AddVisualChild()` and `AddLogicalChild()` calls problem was solved.